# error with gpumat and mat

Tags: c++, opencv

When I compile this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])

{
    try
    {
        cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("file.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
        src.upload(src_host);

        cv::gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::Mat result_host = dst;
        cv::imshow("Result", result_host);
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    catch(const cv::Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

I got the following error:

```
threshold.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
threshold.cpp:19: error: conversion from ‘cv::gpu::GpuMat’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested
```

Does anybody knows why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current versions of OpenCV, the `cv::Mat` class has no overloaded assignment operator or copy constructor which takes argument of type `cv::gpu::GpuMat`. So the following line of your code will not compile.

```
cv::Mat result_host = dst;
```

There are 2 alternatives to this.

First you can pass the `dst` as the argument of the constructor of `result_host`.

```
cv::Mat result_host(dst);
```

Second is that you can call the `download` function of `dst`

```
cv::Mat result_host;
dst.download(result_host);
```

Comment: thanks for your response.

Now when executing this file the following error:


///
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -216 (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in copy, file /home/cbib/Descargas/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/core/src/gpumat.cpp, line 736


/////
you know what can be caused?

Comment: @ChitoWebster... This is because you are using the OpenCV binaries compiled without CUDA support. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228762/opencv-2-4-3rc-and-cuda-4-2-opencv-error-no-gpu-support/13231205#13231205) in which the same issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you should use `download` method of `gpuMat` to convert it to `cv::Mat`:

```
//! downloads data from device to host memory. Blocking calls.
        void download(cv::Mat& m) const;
```

See [this doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/data_structures.html#gpu-gpumat).

Comment: @ChitoWebster my answer was actually also correct (you can try to +1 it). About your new error read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910902/opencv-error-no-gpu-support-library-is-compiled-without-cuda-support