# Compiling error cv::gpu

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV master branch (3.0.0. dev) with CUDA on Ubuntu 12.04, and trying to compile the following opencv with gpu code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("file.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
        src.upload(src_host);

        cv::gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::Mat result_host = dst;
        cv::imshow("Result", result_host);
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    catch(const cv::Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiling command is:

```
g++ testgpu.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lopencv_gpu
```

It has the following compiling errors:

```
testgpu.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
testgpu.cpp:13:51: error: ‘CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE’ was not declared in this scope
         cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("file.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
                                                   ^
testgpu.cpp:17:52: error: ‘CV_THRESH_BINARY’ was not declared in this scope
         cv::gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
                                                    ^
testgpu.cpp:19:31: error: conversion from ‘cv::gpu::GpuMat’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested
         cv::Mat result_host = dst;
                           ^
```

It is something wrong with the installation of OpenCV, or the API change in Opencv 3.0.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error with gpumat and mat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468191/error-with-gpumat-and-mat)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `gpu` module was redesigned in OpenCV 3.0. It was splitted onto several modules, it was renamed to `cuda` and `gpu::` namespace was renamed to `cuda::`. The correct code for OpenCV 3.0:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("file.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        cv::cuda::GpuMat dst, src;
        src.upload(src_host);
        cv::cuda::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::Mat result_host(dst);
        cv::imshow("Result", result_host);
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    catch(const cv::Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fatal error: opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp: No such file or directory

Answer (score 7):

Ah, they've been playing with the constants in master. Expect the `CV_*` prefix removed *almost* anywhere ( except the types, `CV_8U` and such are still alive).

So it's `cv::THRESH_BINARY`, `cv::LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`, but .... `cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY` (you didn't use it now, but i'll spare you the searching ;) )

Sorry, I've no experience with GPU stuff, so i can't solve the last riddle there.

Comment: mostly at the  top of the resp. module headers