# opencv does not recognize macros

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am using Opencv 3 Alpha on Ubuntu 14, everything works fine until I started using some macros... anything like CV_BGR2GRAY, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE;
Have they got changed and where can I find them?

Comment: If you have not used the "using namespace cv" statement, you might have forgotten to use cv::CV_BGR2GRAY but remembered it for functions. That's one possibility that I could think of.

Comment: @Cheeku, I didnt forget using namespace cv, thanks anyways

Comment: I think it is something related to OpenCv 3.0, I have used other macros like namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_NORMAL); and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this forum post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14144/constants-not-found-under-linux/) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368244/compiling-error-cvgpu) it looks like these values have changed in OpenCV 3 to `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` and `cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`.

You can also try including `legacy.hpp` and see if that solves the missing definitions.

Comment: I was not able to include legacy.hpp, do you have any idea where is it located?

Comment: It seems to be `legacy/legacy.hpp` if it exists in your release.