# Compiling Parameter for Visual Studio 2015 (previous work uses g++)

Tags: c++, compilation, window

I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 with CUDA enabled and Windows 10 Home editon. I try to compile the code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368244/compiling-error-cvgpu) using Microsoft Visual Studio 14 (2015). That link uses this command:

`g++ testgpu.cpp -o test pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv -lopencv_gpu` 
(OS Ubuntu).

My question is where paramaters (`pkg-config`, `cflags`, etc) should go in Visual Studio? How to set them in Ms. Visual Studio 2015?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416956/what-is-the-significance-of-pkg-config-in-gcc

Comment: That link asks the meaning of the parameters, while I am asking about where to putting those parameters in VS 2015

Comment: In short: `pkg-config` isn't a g++ parameter, but a tool by it's own. It resolves library dependencies that are needed for a particular package.

Comment: Start to searching pkg-config for Windows, found this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710922/how-to-install-pkg-config-in-windows). Then, how to use it altogether with Ms. Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: I am afraid it would be hard to integrate with a standard MS Visual Studio toolchain.

Comment: So, how to accomplish the aforementioned command in VS2015? How to compile code in this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368244/compiling-error-cvgpu) in VS2015?