# How can I use the GPU module with OPENCV without using Cmake?

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, nvidia

（Environment>）OPENCV is 2.4.11. visual stadio 2015. It is Windows 10 64 bit.

How can I use the GPU module with OPENCV without using Cmake?
The program is as follows.

```
//
// laplacian by GPU
//
// (c)Copyright Spacesoft corp., 2013 rights reserved.
//                               Hiro KITAYAMA
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>                  // <<--

#pragma comment(lib,"opencv_core2411.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"opencv_gpu2411.lib")        // <<--
#pragma comment(lib,"opencv_highgui2411.lib")

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//main
int
main()
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\Daito\\Desktop\\DTWW6svVQAEvgvk.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (src.empty())
        exit(1);

    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuSrc(src);
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuDst;
    cv::gpu::Laplacian(gpuSrc, gpuDst, 0);

    cv::Mat dst(gpuDst);

    cv::imshow("src", src);
    cv::imshow("dst", dst);

    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

It is a program that performs Laplacian processing.

At first, I got an executable file without using Cmake, but when I execute it I get the following error and I can not execute it.

```
OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in EmptyFuncTable::mallocPitch, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\dynamicuda\include\opencv2/dynamicuda/dynamicuda.hpp, line 126
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to use OPENCV's GPU module without using Cmake.
Thank you.

Comment: Well you'll have to use opencv library with GPU support, either you build yourself from source using CMAKE (which should be pretty easy) or get a windows 10 x64bit installer for OpenCV with GPU support ( not sure if its available though )

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12910902/1870232) post

Comment: cross-post to ja.SO: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42832/19110