# How to prepare an environment for using OpenCV and CUDA with python on Windows

Tags: computer-vision

I want to call an OpenCV CUDA function from python, but it's not working.
What installation steps should I take to get CUDA working?

I installed it with the following command.
pip install opencv-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python

NVIDIA CUDA toolkit 12 is already installed.
I created the source and ran it, but an error occurs in the gpu function.

```py
import sys
import cv2

### Read source image
img_src = cv2.imread("./test2.png")

### Run with GPU
img_gpu_src = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
img_gpu_dst = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
for i in range(100):
    img_gpu_src.upload(img_src)
```

python code.py

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:106: error: (-216:No CUDA support) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function 'throw_no_cuda'

Comment: you need to reinstal opencv . and install cuda https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html. And follow https://towardsdatascience.com/opencv-cuda-aws-ec2-no-more-tears-60af2b751c46

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The current development environment is Windows, so I haven't tried the Linux side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910902/opencv-error-no-gpu-support-library-is-compiled-without-cuda-support

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Currently, I understand that the default OpenCV installation does not have a GPU, and I cannot use it unless I build contrib with CMAKE on my own. thank you very much.